# How to get the openerp server time?

Tags: odoo

How to get the openerp server time? I have a scheduler for processing my confirmed records. But I only want to confirm the records whose confirmed date plus 5mins  is less than the current openerp server time. Because my confirmed records should process only after 5 minutes.

Comment: have you noticed OpenERP server is using GMT time ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Python method is:

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.now()
```

Have a look at the standard Python docs for using the `timedelta` to make the 5 minutes difference easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    fields.datetime.now()
```